# Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post content to a user's wall with the help of the graph API and I keep on getting an error message reading: Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.

My code is as follows:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'appID',
    'secret' => 'SECRET',
    'cookie' => true
));

$access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if($user != 0) 
{

    $facebook->api('/me/predict-edit-add:predict', 'post', array(
        'scope' =>  'publish_stream',
        'winning_team' => 'http://samples.ogp.me/413385652011237'
    ));
}
```

And also, I tried changing the URL for the winning_team in array, and I'm not sure what are acceptable values. I tried giving the link to the page of the winning team on my site, and got another error message saying that the value was incorrect.

Thanks, Lance

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to post content to a user's wall

No, not really. What you’re trying to do is publish an Open Graph action, and that’s something different from a simple wall *post*.

Which immediately leads to the question, has your action already been approved by Facebook …?

Comment: Actually, you're right, the action "predict" is a custom action that i created on the open graph dashboard. But, I can't submit it until I post it on my own feed. How do I do that?

Comment: Well, publishing it with your app’s admin/developer user should be no problem, even if the action is not approved yet. / What for are you adding the scope parameter in your API call?

Comment: I read on a similar question on stack overflow that the same error message was generated by not specifying the scope inside of the array. So, I tried it and it didn't work...

Comment: Let’s put it this way: You should be able to publish the action, and get an _action-instance-id_ in return. If and where the published action will show up might be a different matter, depending on your app’s rating etc. But you can worry about that later – getting the API response from publishing the action is the first important thing.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. But, for now, I still don't know how to get rid of that error message.

Comment: OK, winning_team is your object you want to take the action on? How’s that object defined? Your OG sample says it’s type is games.match – does this coincide with your defined object? And again, what’s the scope parameter in your API call supposed to achieve?

Comment: Yes, winning_team is my object that I want to take action on. It's defined as a reference. To be honest, I don't even know what the link to the samples.ogp.me is all about. The scope parameter in my api is supposed to gratn me permission to update the stream.

Comment: I'm someone who learns best by example. Do you think you could show me some sample code of how to publish and open graph action much like the one I'm doing with some other actions/objects?

Comment: Can’t really tell what the reason for the „unexpected error” is from the info so far. I can only suggest you start with the simple examples given in the Facebook docs, and work your way up to your more specific objects and actions from there …